# Retrieving JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

Sorry but yet another question on JavaScript. From my previous post, I was able to conclude that the URL: http://graph.facebook.com/zuck represents a JSON object.

Now my question is how can I retrieve this object in my JavaScript code given the URL and print out the name that corresponds to "first_name" which would be "Mark".

Can someone write a quick example JavaScript code that would take this URL, find the string that corresponds to "first_name" and print it out? Is this easy or am I oversimplifying things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to get the data with jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
to access the name for example you'd have to write something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/zuck', function(data) {
    alert(data.first_name+", "+data.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/zuck", function(json) {
   alert("First Name: " + json.first_name);
 });
```